# Need a predictive (binary outcome) model for a set of binary variables and one continuous variable

Tags: predictive-models, binary-data, nonlinear

I have a data set of about 1600 binary results, that I want to predict from 9 binary variables and a continuous variable.  The relationship between the continuous variable and the result variable by itself isn't linear - most of the true results are for intermediate values of the continuous variable.  I've tried a logistic regression for the binary variables, but I don't know how to create a model that includes the other variable.  My sense is this continuous variable is the strongest predictor, but (at least some) of the other variables are predictive as well. I am familiar with R, but I need a model that is fairly easy to implement outside of R, which is why regression appealed to me.

Comment: How are you trying to create this model?

Comment: So far I have extracted my data into a matrix and fit the logistic regression with glm in R.  I haven't added the continuous variable to the matrix yet, since I didn't know what to do with it in relation to the other data.

Comment: You just add it the same way.

Comment: Try to spline the continuous variable

Comment: I know about splines from curve fitting, but how would that apply here - is it converting that continuous variable into a largish set of categorical values?